# From Eclipse to IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I know some (crazy) people want to [move from IntelliJ to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167400/eclipse-for-intellij-idea-users). On my side, I am moving the "normal way", i.e. from Eclipse 3.3 to IntelliJ 8.0.1

I really like it, but I am a little lost sometimes.

Do you know any specific IntelliJ guide or tutorial created specifically for Eclipse users?

For example, after some tests, I missed some options usefull on Eclipse (I don't say they don't exist in IntelliJ, I just say that I didn't find them !):

- Automatic insert at the correct position of the ';' character
- Actions made on save (format, reorganize and clean imports)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For automatically inserting ';' at the correct position (as well as braces) the last time I've looked (probably Idea 6, maybe 7) it didn't exist. My colleagues always wonder why I insert ';' in stupid places when I'm pairing with them. I told them to notify me when this feature becomes available in Idea, but until now they didn't.

There's the two topmost [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239732/things-possible-in-intellij-that-arent-possible-in-eclipse) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461255/things-possible-in-eclipse-that-arent-possible-in-intellij) (see right column) covering "Things possible in A that aren't possible in B" for both directions - you might find ideas there as well as in the comments to the answers where people tell you what to alternatively do.

Edit (maybe this is better here than in the comments);

...it seems to be *somewhat* possible. See the comment to my [answer to the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461255#answer-462506): . One could argue that CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER is less intuitive than ';', but in Idea you get used to type a lot more of such shortcuts than in eclipse... This comes closest to the functionality you asked for. Hope it helps...

Comment: Ok, so unfortunately it is not possible :(

Comment: ...it seems to be *somewhat* possible. See the comment to my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461255#answer-462506. One could argue that CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER is less intuitive than ';', but in Idea you get used to type a lot more of such shortcuts than in eclipse... Hope it helps...

Answer (score 5):

Check this FAQ in the Jetbrains home page: [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/migration_faq.html). It is not a guide or tutorial, but it goes through some basic concepts that Eclipse users should accustom themselves with when they move.

Comment: Man, you just replied to a question that's almost 5 years old... That has to be some kind of record...

Comment: Indeed, I'm now using IntelliJ every day :o)

Comment: Wow, I hadn't noticed it was a 5-year thread! Glad people are still alive @romaintaz! :-)

Comment: That link do help people new to intellij ,someone may visit the page from google (like me), so I think it doesn't matter.