# Is it possible to configure Eclipse to show lines between brackets?

Tags: java, eclipse

It is possible to configure Eclipse to show lines like it is done in intellJ IDEA, please see screenshot below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As investigation shown there is no such a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=84878), it is not possible, and by the small amount of activity, will not be for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Not the one you are asking but every little helps :), if foldis not enabled.

```
window -> preferences - > type "folding" to left top input field -> enable folding

or from preferences : java -> editor - folding

ctrl+shift+p  may also help a little
```

Comment: Can't find 'type folding' under preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but might work for you :
[intellij_style_mappings_for_eclipse](http://www.jroller.com/ervines/entry/intellij_style_mappings_for_eclipse)

Also spend some time to read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167400/eclipse-for-intellij-idea-users).

Hope this helps.